# Pre-launch report new issue / exception "Last action is expected to be launch > action."

Tags: android, testing, google-play-console

Recently, I've started to receive a new error on the Pre-Launch report on some devices:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Last action is expected to be launch
>   action.

The related Logcat info is this bit:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2 Process:
>   androidx.test.tools.crawler:robov2crawldriver, PID: 15731
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Last action is expected to be launch
>   action.   at
>   androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.z.p.b(PatternCompiler.java:31)
>     at
>   androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.CoreController.crawl(CoreController.java:84)
>     at
>   androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.CoreController.run(CoreController.java:33)

The most curious thing is that I haven't been able to find any results in different search engines by searching for "**Last action is expected to be launch action.**". So it might be a bug on the Firebase Robo Test.

If I check the videos or the execution, there isn't anything that tells me that there was actually a real error.

Has anyone found these errors? Did you manage to get rid of them?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Or at least a reason for that

Comment: I haven't received any more of those. I keep this open just in case it returns (haven't posted many APKs recently though).